# Shell script problem: \r interpreted as a character

Tags: shell-script, terminal

I'm trying to create my own cloud on my new NAS Server but the script used doesn't work.

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

chown -R http:http /volume1/web/owncloud/
chown -R http:http /volume1/web/owncloud/apps/
chown -R http:http /volume1/web/owncloud/config/
chown -R http:http /volume1/web/owncloud/themes/
chown -R http:http /volume1/owncloud/

chown http:http /volume1/web/owncloud/.htaccess

find /volume1/web/owncloud/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 777

find /volume1/web/owncloud/ -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 777
find /volume1/owncloud/ -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 777

chmod 777 /volume1/web/owncloud/.htaccess
```

Here is the answer:

```
Yamakhalah@Jarvis:/$ sudo -su root
Password:
sh-4.3# cd /
sh-4.3# sh /volume1/web/scripts/perm_upd.sh
/volume1/web/scripts/perm_upd.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
chown: cannot access ‘/volume1/web/owncloud/\r’: No such file or directory
chown: cannot access ‘/volume1/web/owncloud/apps/\r’: No such file or directory
chown: cannot access ‘/volume1/web/owncloud/config/\r’: No such file or directory
chown: cannot access ‘/volume1/web/owncloud/themes/\r’: No such file or directory
chown: cannot access ‘/volume1/owncloud/\r’: No such file or directory
/volume1/web/scripts/perm_upd.sh: line 8: $'\r': command not found
chown: cannot access ‘/volume1/web/owncloud/.htaccess\r’: No such file or directory
/volume1/web/scripts/perm_upd.sh: line 10: $'\r': command not found
chmod: invalid mode: ‘777\r’
Try 'chmod --help' for more information.
chmod: invalid mode: ‘777\r’
Try 'chmod --help' for more information.
chmod: invalid mode: ‘777\r’
Try 'chmod --help' for more information.
chmod: invalid mode: ‘777\r’
Try 'chmod --help' for more information.
chmod: invalid mode: ‘777\r’
Try 'chmod --help' for more information.
chmod: invalid mode: ‘777\r’
Try 'chmod --help' for more information.
/volume1/web/scripts/perm_upd.sh: line 12: $'\r': command not found
chmod: invalid mode: ‘777\r’
Try 'chmod --help' for more information.
chmod: invalid mode: ‘777\r’
Try 'chmod --help' for more information.
/volume1/web/scripts/perm_upd.sh: line 15: $'\r': command not found
sh-4.3#
```

Someone could explain me why that `\r` appears everywhere ?

Comment: Presumably the editor that you used to create the script added them - make sure it is configured to use Unix-style line endings instead of DOS/Windows style

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using a Windows style file and copy that to your NAS. You have to convert it to Unix style. [Wikipedia link to more detailed explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations).
Some editors have the capability to save a file to other formats. If your editor can not do this, you can probably use the `dos2unix` utility available for most Linux distributions.

If all of the above options are not helping, [this Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613800/how-to-convert-dos-windows-newline-crlf-to-unix-newline-n-in-bash-script) can probably help you.